# apache shiro and Spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, shiro

I am running into a problem with apache shiro and spring mvc with angularjs.

I am getting a 404 error when I access the angularjs page, http://localhost:8080/app. Inside the app folder there is an index.html, which should be the start of the angularjs app.

below is the shiro.ini

```
# INI configuration is very powerful and flexible, while still remaining succinct.
# Please http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html and
# http://shiro.apache.org/web.html for more.

[main]

authc.loginUrl = /login.html
authc.usernameParam = username
authc.passwordParam = password
authc.rememberMeParam = rememberMe
authc.successUrl = /app


logout.redirectUrl = /logout.html

# use in-memory caching to reduce the number of runtime lookups against the data source.
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

# configure hashed password authentication
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha512CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1

# configure a realm to connect to the data source
daRealm = com.example.security.myRealm
daRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
securityManager.realms = $myRealm

[urls]

/app/** = anon

/favicon.ico = anon
/css/home.css = anon
/images/** = anon
/ = anon
/index.html = anon

/rest/** = anon

/logout = logout

/login.html = authc

/** = authc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
authc.successUrl = /index.html
```

If there is an app directory under app then

```
authc.successUrl = /app/index.html
```

Also as your code i cant figure out what are you securing as only one attribute is with authc

```
/app/** = anon
/favicon.ico = anon
/css/home.css = anon
/images/** = anon
/ = anon
/index.html = anon
/rest/** = anon
/logout = logout
/login.html = authc
```